# user interface issue, can't type in input field on mobile because parent container is draggable sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a multiple photo upload widget for a client that lets him upload photos using ajax, the component after the upload lists the photos in a grid, this photos are basically inside a div container **(which is drag/drop/sortable)** that has the photo uploaded plus some buttons as actions like rotate and set as main, below it has an input to set the title of the pic.

The issue I have is that when in mobile I can't use the title input text because drag and drop functionality takes over and wont let me type something in.

How could I allow for typing in this input text?

I'm using jQuery UI sortable and jQuery UI touch punch

my gallery code is as follows:

```
<ul id="uploaded_image" class="media-gallery list-inline">
    @if(count($data))
      @foreach($data as $item)
      @php
        $fileName = $directory. "/". $item->foto;
      @endphp
        <li class="file-column" id="{{$item->item_id}}">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="foto-container">
              <div onClick="confirmDeletePhoto('{{$item->item_id}}')" class="delete-file" data-id="{{$item->item_id}}" data-file="{{$fileName}}"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
              <div class="dragDrop" title="Arrastre y suelte para ordenar"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
              <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ url("images/photo_upload_edit/".session()->get("current_upload_scenario")."/".$directory."/".$item->foto."?time=".time()) }}" alt="foto">
              <div class="file-toolbar text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btnRotate" data-foto-id="{{$item->item_id}}"><i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i> rotar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btnSetAsPrincipal" data-foto-id="{{$item->item_id}}"><i class="fa @if($item->principal) fa-star @else fa-star-o @endif"></i> principal</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="title @if($item->title) ok @endif">
              <input data-foto-id="{{$item->item_id}}" value="{{$item->title}}" type="text" class="form-control foto-title" placeholder="Titulo de la foto">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      @endforeach
    @endif
</ul>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: No need, i varied the google keywords and found other sources to solve this, the solution is to set draggable=false on the element that you want to use in addition to allow dragging. In my case i just set the input where i hold the title with the attribute draggable equals to false. That was it. Hope this helps others get through the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found out later searching for questions like mine was simple, just add draggable=false to the element you wanna use regardless of dragging the container.

In my case the element was this:

```
<input **draggable=false** data-foto-id="{{$item->item_id}}" value="{{$item->title}}" type="text" class="form-control foto-title" placeholder="Titulo de la foto">
```

Hope these helps :)